# Use bind-key to bind a prefix key to an existing keymap?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

By default, `M-s` a prefix key bound to search-map, containing commands like occur (`M-s o`) and isearch-forward-word (`M-s w`).

I thought I'd change my search-map prefix key to `ESC M-s` in order to use `M-s` for save-buffer (I'm on a Mac and I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> as my meta key).

I like the [bind-key](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el) package, but I can't figure out how to bind a prefix key to a keymap with it. I naively tried:

```
(bind-keys ("M-s"     . save-buffer)
           ("ESC M-s" . search-map))
```

but that doesn't work because `bind-keys` expects an alist whose values are commands, but search-map is a keymap.

I've resorted to doing it without any of `bind-key`'s helper functions:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ESC M-s") search-map)
```

I see `bind-key` has the ability to bind keys within a particular map, and to define a new prefix map, but I don't see a way to bind to an existing map. Maybe there *is* no way to do this using `bind-key` macros, but I thought I'd ask in case anyone knows otherwise.

I'm not totally convinced I want to move the search-map onto a less convenient prefix key just to get saving bound to <kbd>⌘S</kbd>, but I'd like to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `bind-keys` can't do this, `bind-key` can:

```
(bind-key "ESC M-s" search-map)
```